# How to call c# code behind function using bootstrap

Tags: c#, twitter-bootstrap, bootstrap-modal

How to call a function from code behind when the save changes is clicked by the user?

```
<div class="container">
    <div class="modal fade" id="myModal" role="dialog" data-keyboard="false" data-backdrop="static">
        <div class="modal-dialog">
            <div class="modal-content">
                <div class="modal-header">
                    <button type="button" class="close" data-dismiss="modal" aria-label="Close"><span aria-hidden="true">&times;</span></button>
                    <h4 class="modal-title">Warning you're going to delete a data</h4>
                </div>
                <div class="modal-body">
                    <p>Are you sure you want to continue?</p>
                </div>
                <div class="modal-footer">
                    <button type="button" class="btn btn-default" data-dismiss="modal">Close</button>
                    <button type="button"  class="btn btn-primary">Save changes </button>
                </div>
            </div>
            <!-- /.modal-content -->
        </div>
        <!-- /.modal-dialog -->
    </div>
    <!-- /.modal -->
</div>
```

something like this

```
protected void deleterecord(){
}
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

In **MVC** you can do this by sending request to controller's action like

```
@Html.ActionLink("Save Changes", "DeleteRecord", null, new { @class="btn btn-primary" })
```

or

```
<input type="button" value="Save Changes" class="btn btn-primary"
onclick="location.href='@Url.Action("DeleteRecord", "MainController")'" />
```

and add action in controller

```
public ActionResult DeleteRecord()
{
    this.deleterecord();
    return View();
}
```

In **Web Forms** you can append event handler on button click event

```
        <asp:Button
            ID="Button_Save"
            runat="server"
            Text="Save Changes"
            CssClass="btn btn-primary"
            OnClick="Button_Click" />
```

or

```
<input type="button" value="Save Changes" runat="server" class="btn btn-primary"
onclick="Button_Click" />
```

and add code behind handler for this event

```
protected void Button_Click(object sender, EventArgs e)
{
    this.deleterecord();
}
```

Answer (score 0):

You can try this in your web form with a button called btnSave for example:

```
 <button type="button" class="btn btn-default" data-dismiss="modal" onclick="javascript:SaveWithParameter('Hello Michael')">Close</button>
<script type="text/javascript">
function SaveWithParameter(parameter)
{
  __doPostBack('btnSave', parameter)
}
```

And in your code behind add something like this to read the value and operate upon it:

```
public void Page_Load(object sender, EventArgs e)
{
  string parameter = Request["__EVENTARGUMENT"]; // parameter
  // Request["__EVENTTARGET"]; // btnSave
}
```